# Perl data structure

Tags: perl

I'm completely new to perl and I'm trying to build up a data structure which should be rather simple. I have a couple of loops collecting data from the database on each iteration, and I want to be able to store this data in an array of hashmaps.

Now this is where my difficulty currently lies: There is a loop that runs before the data collecting loops and just builds a list of names that will get looped over in the collection loop. What I'm trying to do on that loop is to create an array of hashmaps and just assign the name to a field in the map and leave the others empty.

Once that's done how do I assign a value to an item inside a map contained in an array in perl?

-----EDIT seeing as Im getting down voted----

```
my @characters;
for my $name (@names) {
    my %flinstones = (
        husband   => $name,
        pal       => "",
    );
    push @characters, %flinstones;
}
```

Now how do I set the pal field later in the program?

Comment: Please visit this http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES But personally I would skip ARRAY and just make HASH with names as a key. (of course if name unique... KISS principle)

Comment: Not that this is the least bit relevant to your question, but did you really mean "flinstones" or did you mean "[flintstones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flintstones)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl has three basic variable structures: Scalars variables (`$foo`), Arrays (`@foo`), and Hashes (`%foo`).

Perl allows you to use *references* to these structures. A *reference* is a pointer to a particular variable type. For example, I could have a reference to a *Hash* or an *Array*. It's using references where you can build more complex structures.

It's important to keep in mind that these more complex structures are *references* and can be tricky for someone new in Perl to understand. For example:

```
@foo = (1, 2, 3, 4);      # This is a standard array.
%foo = (1, 2, 3, 4);      # This is a hash with two items. 1 & 3 are keys. 2 & 4 data.
$foo = [1, 2, 3, 4];      # A reference to a nameless array that contains four items
$foo = {1, 2, 3, 4};      # A reference to a nameless hash that contains four items.
```

Note that when I merely change the parentheses to square brackets or curly braces, I am now talking about references and not hashes or arrays. Also note that hashes can convert back and forth betweens arrays and hashes.

```
@foo = (1, 2, 3, 4);      # This is an array of four numbers
%foo = @foo;              # %foo is a hash with two data items  1=> 2 and 3 => 4
@bar = %foo;              # @bar is another array!
```

No wonder people new to Perl can get confused by this!

Let's take a look at that loop:

```
my @characters;
for my $name (@names) {
    my %flinstones = (
        husband    => $name,
        pal        => "",
    );
    push @characters, %flinstones;   # What's this?
}
```

In your `@characters` array, you're pushing in an array of four items, and not a hash!

The `push` is taking `%flinstones` is an array context (well, *list* context). If `%flinstones` is

```
husband => Fred,
pal     => "",
```

The push will look like this:

```
@characters = ( "husband", "Fred", "pal", "" );
```

The next time it executes (and assuming `$name` gets changed to `Barney`), you'll see this:

```
@characters = ("husband", "Fred", "pal", "", "husband", "Barney", "pal", "");
```

You're basically destroying your structure of your hash with that loop. Not what you want.

What you might have meant is this:

```
push @characters, \%flinstones;   # See the difference from the above?
```

The backslash in front of `%flinstones` says you're pushing a *reference* to that `%flinstone` hash into your array, and not the items (both keys and values) into your array. That one little backslash makes a *big* difference in your program. Even worse, both `push` statements are grammatically correct. Your Perl program will run with either one.

No wonder new Perl users find references so confusing!

After your loop, your array will look something like this:

```
$characters[0] = { husband => "Fred", pal => "" };
$characters[1] = { husband => "Barney", pal => "" };
```

Note that curly braces talk about a *hash reference*! Note that you have an array of hash references this way, and your hash structure is saved. You could `pop` off each hash reference (and remember it's a reference!) or talk about `$character[0]->{husband}` being set to `Fred`.

I highly recommend you read the [Perl Tutorial on References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). I also recommend that you look at the [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) module. You can use this tool to print out your complex data structure and see what's going on.

By the way, you usually see a hash of hashes for things like this. Imagine instead of using an array of `@characters`, you use a hash of `%characters` keyed by the first name of that character:

```
my %characters;
$character{Fred}   = {};   #Some hash reference. We'll fill it out later...
$character{Barney} = {};
$charcater{Wilma}  = {};
$character{Betty}  = {};
```

Now, we can talk about each character! Let's fill in some fields:

```
$character{Fred}->{spouse}   = "Wilma";
$character{Fred}->{pal}      = "Barney";
$character{Barney}->{spouse} = "Betty";
$character{Barney}->{pal}    = "Fred";
$character{Betty}->{spouse}  = "Barney";
$character{Betty}->{pal}     = "Wilma";
```

So, we have a hash, and each entry is a sub-hash (a reference to another hash) that contains two entries (one for `spouse` and one for `pal`. We can use this structure to track complex relationships.

In fact, it's likely people have more than one pal. Let's make `pal` point to an array!

```
$characher{Fred}->{pal} = [];  This is an array reference!
push @{ $character{Fred}->{pal} }, ("Barney", "Joe");
```

Now, `$character{Fred}` has two pals! Note the *dereferencing* syntax to turn that _array reference (`$character{Fred}->{pal}`) back into an array, so I can push items into it.

Read the tutorial. It's pretty simple, and then play around with references until you have a better idea what's going on. Remember too that references and hashes need to be *referenced* and *dereferenced*, and that the type of data grouping parameters you use (parentheses, curly brackets, or square brackets) can make a big difference on whether you're talking about a reference or an array or hash, and even what type of reference you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I think your data structure doesn't work as well as you think it does - an array is for an ordered sequence of items.

A hash is for an unordered set of key-value pairs. It's not all that usual to nest hashes inside an array, for that reason.

The problem you'll be having with that 'push' is that if you treat a hash like an array, it actually works ... like an array. Internally, they're both 'sequences of scalars' and the key difference is that an array maintains it's order, where a hash just ensures the relationships between keys and values persist.

For example:

```
my @array = ( "husband", "fred", "pet", "" );
my %hash = @array;

foreach my $key ( keys %hash ) {
    print "$key = $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

This works in reverse too:

```
@array = %hash;
print join (":", @array );
```

So what you're doing is shoving into `@characters` `("husband", $name, "pal", "" )`. That's even less likely to be what you want to do.

So first off - to insert your hash into your array, you need to put a hash reference:

```
push @characters, \%flinstones;    ## ITYM flintstones
```

Then you'll be able to:

```
for my $character ( @characters ) {
   print $character -> {'husband'};
}
```

But I don't actually think that structure does what you want it, so you *may* want to consider taking an object oriented approach instead.

Comment: Internally hashes and arrays are the same. They can be coerced back and forth. I'll amend the answer accordingly.

Comment: If you do `%hash = @array` - provided it's an even numbered array - you'll turn it into a set of key-value pairs, such that 'even' elements are keys, and odd elements are values. You can do the same in reverse, and turn a hash into a long list of scalars. But the ordering will be strange.

Comment: ah, your "treat..like an array" means use in list context.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid the array of hashes/hashes of arrays and spend a little bit of time looking at how to do OO in Perl.  It's a little bit more work up-front but will save maintenance headaches further down the line.  you can do a `man perlboot` or have a look at the online [perl OO tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_oo_perl.htm)